# How to check if the stream of rows has ended

Tags: talend

Is there a way for me to know if the stream of rows has ended? That is, if the job is on the last row?
What im trying to do is for every 10 rows do something, my problem are the last rows, for example in 115 rows, the last 5 wont happen but i need them to.

Comment: Im looking for something like row1.hasNext() but in talend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality in Talend which tells you if you're on the last row. You can work around this using one of the following:

- Get the row count beforehand. For instance, if you have a file, you
  can use `tFileRowCount` to count the number of rows, then when you
  process your file, you use a variable for your current row
  number, and so you can tell if you've reached the last row. If your
  data come from a database, you could either issue a query that
  returns the total number of rows beforehand, or modify your main
  query to return the total number of rows in an additional column and
  use that (using ranking functions).
- Do some processing after the subjob has ended: There may be situations
  where you need a special processing for the last row, you can achieve
  this by getting the last row processed by the previous subjob (which
  you have already saved, for instance, by putting a `tSetGlobalVar`
  after your target, when your subjob is done, your variable contains the last written value).

**Edit**

For your use case, what you could do is first store the result of the API call in memory using `tHashOutput`, then read it with a `tHashInput` in order to process it, and you'll know then how many rows you have retrieved using `tHashOutput`'s global variable `tHashOuput_X_NB_LINE`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, unfortunately this answer doesnt apply to me, since im getting my data from an API witch i dont have control of.

Comment: Thank you again, probably is better that calling the API twice (one for counting and another for the actual processing).